# Disable products in same category if an item is added to the cart - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been looking for a solution to disable certain products from the same category if one of the items is added to the cart.
For example: I have 1 category with products from A to E.
If I add product A to the cart I want to disable products B and E, so they can't be added to the cart during the same shopping session.

Is there a way to achieve this?
Many thanks.

Comment: I don't have code, but instead of hiding, do an add-to-cart validation by applying your required logic. You can find code online for add-to-cart validation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you actually have two options ,one is to customize your own plugin and insert it to your website but this actually takes time .The other way is to download a wholesale and b2b plugin , these plugins usually contain features as the one you are looking for , so you will be able to activate the feature that you want .

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by validating the cart whenever an item is added to it.

You can do that by editing your theme (or child theme) *functions.php* file or by using your custom plugin.

You can use the following hook *'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation'*

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'allowed_item_category_in_the_cart', 10, 2 );

function allowed_item_category_in_the_cart( $passed, $product_id) {
  $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

  // Get product categories
  $product_category_ids = $product->get_category_ids();

  // Then you iterate through each cart item
  foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key=>$cart_item ){
    $cart_product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $cart_product = wc_get_product($cart_product_id);
    $cart_product_category_ids = $cart_product->get_category_ids();
    if (array_intersect($cart_product_category_ids, $product_category_ids))
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

PS: I just wrote this code. I didn't have time to test it yet.
Let me know your feedback.